# Where can I find Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller driver?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, intel-graphics, proprietary-drivers, graphic-card

It seems that Mint 17.3 came out lacking the Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core Graphics Controller driver. Where can I download it in order to install it manually?

UPDATE: Why I believe that this driver is missing.

Me and my coworkers use PCs of the same model, with the exactly the same hardware. I use Mint for some time already, so I updated my installation to 17.3 instead of reinstalling the system. But three of my colleagues switched from their previous distros to Mint 17.3, and they are experiencing video-related glitches, but I'm not. We compared our drivers listing, and noticed that my installation has a specific driver, while theirs are using a generic one.

When I run `lspci` on my PC, this is what I get:

```
sudo lspci
<stuff>
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
<more stuff>
```

But they get this:

```
sudo lspci
<stuff>
0:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
<more stuff>
```

The fact that I updated my installation instead of reinstalling, like they did, is the only difference that we noticed, so we are blaming 17.3.

Comment: Could you explain what gives you the impression that Mint 17.3 is lacking in this respect? I've been using E3-1200v3 CPUs since mid-2013 with no major issues, and since Mint 17.3 is based on Ubuntu 14.04, I wouldn't expect any problem.